# 2本の折れ線グラフのツールチップのTitleに、それぞれ別の文字列を表示させたい。

Tags: javascript, chart.js

2本の折れ線グラフは今年の売上と去年の売上を表示しています。

```
$xlabelThis = '20/03','20/04','20/05','20/06';
$xlabelLast = '19/03','19/04','19/05','19/06';
```

一方の折れ線グラフはPHPで宣言した `$xlabelThis` をそのままツールチップのTitleとして用いますが、もう一方の折れ線グラフは `$xlabelLast` の内容を反映させたいです。
ご教示いただけると幸いです。

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("uriageChart");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',

    data: {
      labels: [{$xlabelThis}],

      datasets: [
        {
          label: '今年(万円)',
          lineTension: 0,
          data: [3000,7000,4000,3000],
          borderColor: "rgba(255,0,0,1)",
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
        },
        {
          label: '去年(万円)',
          lineTension: 0,
          data: [1000,3000,5000,2000],
          borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1)",
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
        }
      ],
    },
    options: {
      tooltips: {
          mode: 'nearest',
          intersect: false,
          callbacks: {
              title: function (tooltipItem, data){
                  return '';
              },
              label: function(tooltipItem, data){
                  return tooltipItem.yLabel.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') +' 円';
              }
          }
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: '売上'
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            callback: function(value, index, values){
              return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') +' 円';
            }
          }
        }]
      },
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

[Chart.js Tooltip Callback](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks)

や [サンプルページ](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/tooltips/callbacks.html)を見るとわかりますが

Tooltips の callback の中で タイトル等を書き換える事ができます。

改造したところは

```
var xlabelThis  = [ '20/03', '20/04', '20/05', '20/06'];
var xlabelLast = ['19/03', '19/04', '19/05', '19/06'];
var titles = [xlabelThis, xlabelLast];
```

```
tooltips: {
callbacks: {
 title: function (tooltipItem, data) {
  var title = titles[tooltipItem[0].datasetIndex];
  return title[tooltipItem[0].index];
}
```

のように `tooltipItem[0].datasetIndex` が 0 または 1 で 今年、昨年が切り替えられ
`tooltipItem[0].index` で 何番目の要素なのかがわかるので、
あとは 表示したいタイトルを文字列で返すだけです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]